# Centered DIV - auto height

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

XHTML:

```
<div id="container">
 // contents
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { margin: 0 auto; width: 940px; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; }
```

The div is centered on the page with `margin: 0 auto` and I use `overflow: hidden` to allow the DIV to automatically expand down to the height of its contents.

I have some content in the DIV which has a box-shadow on it. The problem is due to the overflow: hidden rule the shadow does not fully appear on the page. The only ways around this I have found:

1. Take out overflow: hidden - but then the container DIV doesn't expand down.
2. Use height / min-height on #container - however this wont work well with all pages on the site.
3. Use float: left - but then the DIV isn't centered on the page.

Anybody got any more suggestions for this?

Comment: Please show the HTML + CSS for an example.

Comment: show us your code, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Xcekn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the many clearfix techniques.  That will let you remove `overflow:hidden` and fix the cropped `box-shadow`.

Here's a recent article on the topic: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure some margin on the div would solve it, but if you show some more code it's easier to check.

Comment: That would fit for a comment but not an answer for me!

Comment: Margin on the div is my answer.